# How to select all the entries in the first group when query with GROUP BY in SQL?

Tags: sql, django-queryset

Take the following dataset `Demo` as an example:

```
attr_A    attr_B
0         8
1         6
2         6
2         8
3         6
```

Here is my question, how can I select all the entries in the first group when I apply the SQL statements such as `SELECT * FROM Demo GROUP BY attr_B ORDER BY attr_B`? And the corresponding query result should be:

```
attr_A   attr_B
1         6
2         6
3         6
```

P.S. Here I also tag with `django-queryset` because my current project applies `django`, but I think if I know how to do that in SQL, it's not hard to implement it in django. Thus my question title and description only contain SQL issues.

Comment: if you group on attr_b you'll have 8 and 6 as value in attr_b result.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Demo
WHERE attr_B = (SELECT MIN(attr_B) FROM Demo)
```

You don't need GROUP BY clause if you want to select all entries

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it in SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Demo 
WHERE attr_B = (SELECT MIN(attr_B) FROM Demo)
```

If your RDBMS supports window functions then you can use `RANK`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT *,
          RANK() OVER (ORDER BY attr_B) AS rnk
   FROM Demo) AS t
WHERE t.rnk = 1
```

Comment: That's clear for me. I'm wondering if there is a strategy without applying sub-query.

Comment: I think you need to remove the GROUP BY clause for this to work.  Otherwise you will only get a single record; with the single value telling you that attr_B=6

Comment: @Taemyr Yes, you are right. The OP wants to select all records within the same group.